# CSOM modify "new discussion" link when creating discussion board

Tags: list, discussion-board, csom

I am creating a discussion board via `CSOM` and am wondering if there is a way to modify the "new discussion" text when creating the discussion board?

[image]

Here is a snippet of how I am creating the list:

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{
      Web web = ctx.Web;
      ListCreationInformation lci = new ListCreationInformation();
      lci.Title = "My Title";
      lci.TemplateType = (int)ListTemplateType.DiscussionBoard;
      List lst = web.Lists.Add(lci);
      .
      .
      .
```

Is there a property I can access using the `ListCreationInformation` object to modify this text?

Answer (score 0):

The text "new discussion" and the like is stored in javascript files named string.js and instrings.js files which are stored in layouts folder in physical path in a given language (LCID). You can make changes in those file by updating the value of `Strings.STS.L_SPDiscHeroLinkFormat`. However, it will update the text in all Discussion lists present in a praticular lanaguage everywhere in the farm. A better approach may be to use JQuery/JavaScript to update the text in a given list. 
Source: [SharePoint: strings.js and instrings.js](http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2015/02/sharepoint-2013-stringsjs.html)